# Wrong bounding object when translate viewport in FabricJS, user can't select object when click on object

Tags: css, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

Please help me resolve this problem.
1. I have a text display at postion : left: 10, top: 10.
2. Using viewportTransform to move viewPort to new position : translate by X axis 100 & by Y axis 100 
3. The text object is moving to new position 
**Expected:**
User can selected text Object ( 'hello world' ) by click on the text ( at new position )

**Actual:**
At first time, user can't click on text Object. & object bounder still at old position ( left: 10, top: 10 ). ( see attach image)
Please check in my demo code. 
I'm using Fabricjs version 2.4.0 this demo

How to pass through this problem?
Thank you !

[image: Wrong cursor position]

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
  // set canvas equal size with div
  $(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
  $(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());
 
 canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    selectionLineWidth: 2,
    width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
    height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
  });

  canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;

  // Add a text to canvas
  var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', { left: 10, top: 10 });
  canvas.add(text);
  
  // Transform View
  canvas.viewportTransform[4] = 100;
  canvas.viewportTransform[5] = 100;
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: gray;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.js"></script>


<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [object.setCoords()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords), it will set bounding cordinate after change. And check [When-to-call-setCoords](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("editorCanvas");
// set canvas equal size with div
$(canvasObject).width($("#canvasContainer").width());
$(canvasObject).height($("#canvasContainer").height());

canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editorCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  selectionLineWidth: 2,
  width: $("#canvasContainer").width(),
  height: $("#canvasContainer").height()
});

canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;

// Add a text to canvas
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
  left: 10,
  top: 10
});
canvas.add(text);

// Transform View
canvas.viewportTransform[4] = 100;
canvas.viewportTransform[5] = 100;
setObjectCoords();
canvas.requestRenderAll();

function setObjectCoords(){
  canvas.forEachObject(function(object){
    object.setCoords();
  })
}
```

```css
#canvasContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.js"></script>


<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="editorCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank Durga, It's a great answer. By the way, if I have many objects in the canvas, how to update all Coords for them ? Is there any shorter solution for that ?

Comment: @ThoBuiNgoc, you can use `canvas.forEachObject` to loop through all object. Answer updated.

Comment: Durga, Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but you could do the following:

```
let vpt = [...canvas.viewportTransform];
vpt[4] = 100;
vpt[5] = 100;
canvas.setViewportTransform(vpt);
```

Had the same issue and that solved it.